# Submit button on form B attempts to submit form A instead

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I have a superfish menu containing two forms, a search box in superfish tab 1 and a newsletter signup in tab 3. The search form works fine, and the newsletter signup works fine so long as the search form isn't present on the page. But when both are present, the submit button on the newsletter signup form appears to try and submit a search instead, which not only doesn't sign the user up for the newsletter, but it doesn't search for anything either.

My code goes like this:

```
<form class="search-form" action="/search/node" method="post" id="search-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="container-inline form-wrapper" id="edit-basic"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-keys">
 <input type="text" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="" size="20" placeholder="  Search this site" maxlength="255" class="form-text" />
</div>
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Go" class="form-submit" /></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form--JTbYKjZwG8SjIstLVU7J0HOiZZiSoB88bE4VoRYTG4" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="HoVlLGidOtcgITb3XmNhvH7mKKzW8ldmnahr3t0HGAU" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_form" />

<many other divs>

<form class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/content/newsletter-signup" method="post" id="webform-client-form-22" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div>
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-email webform-container-inline" id="webform-component-email">
 <input class="email form-text form-email required" type="email" id="edit-submitted-email" placeholder="Email address" name="submitted[email]" size="24" />
</div>
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline" id="webform-component-name">
 <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-name" name="submitted[name]" value="" placeholder="Name" size="14" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" /> <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="details[sid]" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="details[page_num]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="details[page_count]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="details[finished]" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-I8MgMoURjB6BhqJATKhhNZ5nAUwk855bGWgxH75Gs5Q" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="IKALClB6fmkRPFA6Ko8VIbBN2uDEwpVBxFM6w2_2JAo" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="webform_client_form_22" />
</div></form>
```

How can I get the submit button on the second (newsletter signup) form to submit that form and not the search?

Comment: You probably have a nesting problem (for example both submit buttons are inside the same form)

Comment: your first form  'search-form' not over try to over before second form 'webform-client-form'  start

Comment: in your code over 1 div tag and form tag before <many other divs> line

Comment: where you end up form with id="search-form"?

Comment: Thanks all for spotting the missing </form>. My eyes must have glazed over there. Fixed now. Thanks again.